# What is the simplified form of the generalized eigen space when the characteristic polynomial does not split in the given field.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}.$ Let $T$ be a inear operator on $V$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ of algebraic multiplicity $m.$ Now suppose that the characteristic polynomial does not split in $F.$ Then is it true that the generalized eigen space corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is given by $$S=\{x \in V : (T-\lambda I)^mx=0\},$$ where the Generalized eigen space of $\lambda$ $G(\lambda,T)$ is defined as $\{x \in V : (T-\lambda I)^ix=0\;\text{for}\;\text{some}\;i \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}\}.$

I have seen the proof when the Characteristic polynomial splits in the field $\mathbb{F}.$ In our case to start with we should assume that $m < \text{dim}(V)$ so that $c_{T}(X)=(X-\lambda)^mP(X).$ Clearly for all $v \in V$ $P(T)(v) \in G(\lambda,T).$ And also $S \subseteq G(\lambda,T).$ How can I prove the converse ? Any help will be appreciated. Many Thanks.

Comment: What is the proof when the polynomial splits? Maybe only some minor changes are needed to make it work in general.

Comment: If the characteristic polynomial does not split, there is no such $\lambda\in\mathbb F$ is there? Instead $\lambda$ is an element of the splitting field.

Comment: What if the ch polynomial is $(X-1)^2(X^2+1) \in \mathbb{R}[X],$ where $\lambda =1$ and $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: By split of a polynomial I mean split completely into linear factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the characteristic polynomial does not split into linear factors I would approach this as follows.

A way to prove the existence of most of the canonical forms is the observation that having a linear transformation $T:V\to V$ allows us to turn $V$ into an $\Bbb{F}[x]$-module by letting $x$ act as $T$. More precisely, if $v\in V$ and $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i\in\Bbb{F}[x]$ are arbitrary, we define
$$
p(x)\cdot v=\sum_{i=0}^na_i T^i(v).
$$
Anyway, let's see where this approach takes us.

As $V$ was assumed to be finite dimensional, it becomes a finitely generated $\Bbb{F}[x]$-module. A polynomial ring over a field is a PID (a Euclidean domain even), so the structure of f.g. modules over a PID allows us to write $V$ as a direct sum oof cyclic modules
$$
V=\bigoplus_{j=1}^rV_j,
$$
where each summand $V_j\simeq \Bbb{F}[x]/\langle p_j(x)\rangle$ for some non-constant polynomial $p_j(x)\in\Bbb{F}[x]$.

If $p_j(x)=\prod_\ell q_\ell(x)^{a_\ell}$ is a factorization of $p_j(x)$ into a product of powers of irreducible polynomials $q_\ell(x)$, then the polynomial variant of the Chinese Remainder Theorem allows us to further split the submodules
$$
\Bbb{F}[x]/\langle p_j(x)\rangle=\bigoplus_\ell\Bbb{F}[x]/\langle q_\ell(x)^{a_\ell}\rangle.
$$
Putting this all together we see that $V$ can be written as a direct sum of modules of the form $\Bbb{F}[x]/\langle r(x)^a\rangle$ for some irreducible polynomial
$r(x)\in\Bbb{F}[x]$ and positive integer $a$. Such a decomposition (into submodules) is automatically also a decomposition into $T$-stable subspaces.

Let's extract one more thing from the theory of modules over a PID. To each irreducible polynomial $r(x)$ we can define the $r$-power torsion submodule
$$
V_r:=\{v\in V\mid r(x)^k\cdot v=0\ \text{for some integer $k>0$}\}.
$$
In my opinion the subspaces $V_r$ are the natural analogue of the generalized eigenspaces. After all, should $\Bbb{F}$ be algebraically closed, we would necessarily have $r(x)=x-\lambda$ for some $\lambda\in\Bbb{F}$, and the above definition of $V_r$ becomes the definition of a generalized eigenspace.

The submodule $V_r$ is the direct sum of all those earlier summands $\Bbb{F}[x]/\langle q_\ell(x)^{a_\ell}\rangle$ where the irreducible polynomial $q_\ell(x)=r(x)$.

---

My main point was that when the characteristic polynomial doesn't split into linear factors, it feels natural to lump together *conjugate eigenvalues*, i.e. the zeros of an irreducible factor of the characteristic polynomial. The above subspaces $V_r$ become, upon the appropriate extension of scalars, the sum of generalized eigenspaces belonging to all those conjugate eigenvalues.

It is easy to build an analogue of a Jordan block in this setting. A submodule of the form $\Bbb{F}[x]/\langle r(x)^a\rangle$ then corresponds with an $ab\times ab$ matrix, $b=\deg r(x)$. Along its diagonal we have $b\times b$-blocks representing $r(x)$. We can arrange those diagonal blocks to become, say, companion matrices of $r(x)$. Then, on top of the main diagonal we have blocks of the form $I_b$, analogous to those extra $1$ on top of the diagonal of a Jordan block in the case $b=1$.

Comment: In  2ndlast paragraph do you wanted to say that it is enough to consider that the ch polynomial splits completely in the base field ? In my understanding  If $K$ be the splitting field of the ch polynomial then one may consider the vector space $K \otimes_{\mathbb{F}} V$ over K (By extension of scalars). I know that the induced linear operator on $K \otimes_{\mathbb{F}} V$ also has the same ch polynomial. Then the generalized eigen space corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has same dimension in both the cases. If this is it please confirm me so that I may try to prove this. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. That's what happens. Any $\Bbb{F}$-automorphism of $K$ (acting on that tensor product on the left factor) leaves the spaces $K\otimes V_r$ invariant, and permutes the generalized eigenspaces belonging to conjugate eigenvalues.